# Windows is not giving option for ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, windows, windows-8

I was using windows 8.1 . I have dual boot my computer with ubuntu using something else option. When I restart my computer it automatically boots up with windows without giving any option to select between windows and ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by fast start up which causes windows to always put the system into a suspend to disk state so when the computer turns back on it loads out of ram skipping any OS selections. While you can technically get around this by cutting power to the computer (so the bios loads again) or by using the restart option instead of the shutdown option in windows its generally recommended you disable fast start up on dual boot systems. Windows file system will be left in a hibernated state which Linux NTFS driver doesn't handle.

You can disable fast start up in the Windows control panel by going to Power Options, "Choose what the power buttons do", "Change settings that are currently unavailable", Uncheck "Turn on fast startup" and save changes.

You should then be able to restart or shutdown and repower and have an OS selector.